# Different match results from grep and sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm using the following regular expression to match github repo paths:
    :/
However, I get different matching results from `grep` and `sed`:

```
$ sed -nr 's|[:/]([^/]+/[^/]+)$|\1|' <<< 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo'

$ sed -nr '/[:\/]([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)$/p' <<< 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo'  

$ grep -Eo '[:/]([^/]+/[^/]+)$' <<< 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo'
/myuser/myrepo
```

Shouldn't the results of those two commands be equivalent (except `sed` omitting the leading `[:/]`)?

grep: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
sed: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
OS: Mac OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want equivalent `sed` as your `grep` command then use:

```
sed -r 's#^.*([:/][^/]+\/[^/]+)$#\1#' <<< 'https://github.com/myuser/myrepo'
/myuser/myrepo
```